# Is there any way to pass the validation of NOT REQUIRED v-text-field rules?

Tags: forms, validation, textfield, vuetify.js

I tried to validate v-text-field for entering number only but it is **not required** but the rules deny to pass the validation.

I used v-form, v-text-field and rules of v-text-field.

```
<template>
  <v-form ref="form">
    <v-text-field
      v-model="name"
      :label="label"
      :rules="rules"
      @blur="changeValue"
      clearable
    ></v-text-field>
  <v-btn @click="send">submit</v-btn>
</v-form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      name: "",
      rules: [
        v =>
          v.length <= 50 || "maximum 50 characters",
        v =>
          (v.length > 0 && /^[0-9]+$/.test(v)) || "numbers only"
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeValue(event) {
      this.$emit("changeValue", event.target.value);
    },
    send() {
      const valid = this.$refs["form"].validate(); // doesn't pass
      if (valid) {
        this.$store.dispatch("xxx", {
          ...
        });
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

When the submit button was clicked, error message of v-text-field is shown and `valid` is false.

Clicked X(the clear icon), The error message is also shown on console:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A bit late, but i have solved it with this function:

```js
rules: [
  v => {
    if (v) return v.length <= 50 || 'maximum 50 characters';
    else return true;
  },
],
```

Answer (score 1):

i use this way one for email and one for name

```
nameRules: [  
  v => v.length <= 10 || 'Name must be less than 10 characters',
],
emailRules: [      
  v =>( v.length ===0 || /.+@.+/.test(v) )   || 'E-mail must be valid',
],
```

Answer (score 0):

by adding `!v ||`  to any rule you can make it "not required, but if present, then must follow the rule'.
So this is the code for your rule section:

```
rules: [
        v => !v || (v && v.length <= 50) || `Maximum 50 characters`,
        v => !v || (v && v.length > 0 && /^[0-9]+$/.test(v)) || "numbers only"
]
```